# D3 change the charge of a single node

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

When I click on a node, my node get bigger, and as it's now bigger, I would like his charge to repulse other node even more. How can I change the charge of a node ?

Code excerpt:

```
[...]

//draw new graph
d3.json(file, function(error, graph) {

force
.nodes(graph.nodes)
.links(graph.links)
.start();

var nodeCircle = node.append("circle")
.attr("id", function(d) { return "node"+d.id })
.attr("class", function(d) {return "node "+d.nodeclass; })
.attr("r", 8) // R = Radius of node
.style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; }) // Will overwrite CSS style
.on("click",function(d) {

    //When CTRL key is pressed ....
    if (d3.event.ctrlKey) {
        if(d3.select(this).attr('r')==8){
            d3.select(this).attr('r', 12);
            //ToDo: node Charge = -1000
        }else{
            d3.select(this).attr('r', 8);
            //ToDo: node Charge = -500
        }
    }

}).call(force.drag);
[...]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function click(d1,i){
    force.charge(
            function(d2,i){
                if(d2!=d1)
                    return ...;//calculate your charge for other nodes
                else
                    return ...;//calculate your charge for the clicked node
            });

        force.start();
 }
```

This works fine for me!! Correct me if Im wrong..!

Comment: Had almost this exact scenario - thanks for providing good examples and helping clarify that the `force` needed to be 're-charged' and re-started. I had thought providing a function to `charge` initially would result in a "living" charge that would be re-evaluated on each tick.

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout):

> force.charge([charge])
>
> If charge is specified, sets the charge strength to the specified value. If charge is not specified, returns the current charge strength, which defaults to -30. If charge is a constant, then all nodes have the same charge. Otherwise, if charge is a function, then the function is evaluated for each node (in order), being passed the node and its index, with the this context as the force layout; the function's return value is then used to set each node's charge. The function is evaluated whenever the layout starts.

So what you need to do is specify a function for `charge()` that gives the different charge for the node in question and start the layout again.

Comment: I've read that, but the documentation does not provide any code example, and all my attempts to implement it in the context above  so far failed. force.charge() isn't explicit on how to access the force() function from a node... at least for me. I know the solution is simple, I just can't find it :p

Comment: You need to save the force layout in a variable, e.g. `var force = d3.layout.force(); ... force.charge(function(d) { ... }); force.start();`

Comment: Ok, but how do I target 1 single node ? I don't want to change the whole force, but only a node. And the change does not come from the data at all... Oh, wait... so the click has to change a property in the data, and then I re-run the general charge function... ???

Comment: The only thing you need to do is identify the node with the different charge -- in the click handler, you have both data and index for it. So in your charge function you only need to check if the current index matches the index of the clicked node and if so apply the different charge.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I am sorry I am so late for that ... Can you explain how to make the check for the node in action using code?

Comment: Something like `.charge(function(d, i) { return (d == datumOfNodeInQuestion) ? someCharge : someOtherCharge; })`.